# How to run a Bash Script file in Python with arguments

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am looking to run the following bash script with python:

```
sed -n -e '/SCN/,/^\s*$/p' $@ > Junction-Links.txt
```

The bash script is saved as ext-jun-links.sh and I want to run it using Python to pass a file name in place of the $@.

I am currently trying to use the below code to do so:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
    
subprocess.run(["./ext-jun-links.sh","NETL1405.TXT"], shell=True)
```

However, this gives me the error below:

```
'ext-jun-links.sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is there a way to solve this error? The bash file runs fine when using PowerShell with the following code, so that's not the issue:

```
bash ext-jun-links.sh 'NETL1405.TXT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's cus' you're trying to execute a bash script via PowerShell.

```
bash ext-jun-links.sh 'NETL1405.TXT'
```

This works, because you're feeding ext-jun-links.sh and 'NETL1405.TXT' as params to bash.

try:

```
subprocess.run(["bash", "./ext-jun-links.sh","NETL1405.TXT"], shell=True)
```

Comment: Do you really need `shell=True` for that?